# swiftui button show in preview, but never show in simulator or device

Tags: swiftui, simulator, preview

please see the below image, I just have one button in swiftui content view.
you can see this button show in preview fine, but never show in similuator, or device.  just blank there.

any idea what it is ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your simulator or device can not support `[Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]`, if you change `[Color("DarkGreen"), Color("LightGreen")]` to `[Color.red, Color.green]`, you will see it.